# Linux guest graceful shutdown in Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v, shutdown

What mechanism Hyper-V use to signal a Linux guest to gracefully shut down?

Somehow CoreOS does gracefully shut down, but another Linux doesn't (it is just abruptly powered off)

Comment: Do you have the Hyper-V Guest Integration Services installed?

Comment: They are only kernel modules, and they all are already in the mainline kernel and loaded on my box. So yes, I have them installed and operating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. `drivers/hv/hv_util.c` calls `orderly_poweroff()` from `kernel/reboot.c` which subsequently fails to find `/sbin/poweroff` and does only a minimal cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

If i am not mistaken, Hyper v integration is what causes this. I have not used CoreOS but usually this is what causes your virtual server to shutdown correctly.

In terminal, issue the command lsmod. On CoreOS you will (if i am right) see that it lists Hyperv services(hv_vmbus, hv_netvsc, etc) on the other it does not. Some Linux distros come with it built in and others you can add it. 
If this is not it, comment below and i will delete this answer.

Comment: I have the modules loaded. They are in mainline kernel, so only distributions with very old kernels need backported modules from MS.

Answer (score 0):

*This does not answer your question as detailed, as you might want to know. I want to add this as an answer nonetheless, as the detailed technical answers comes close to be off-topic (non-supported environment).*

You want to look at the documentation of [Linux and FreeBSD Virtual Machines on Hyper-V](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531030.aspx) on what distributions are supported. Check the section of the individual distribution and version and see, if the **Core** is supported.

> **Core**
>   Integrated shutdown:
>   With this feature, an administrator can shut down virtual machines from the Hyper-V Manager. For more information, see Operating system shutdown.
>   <sub>Source: [Feature Descriptions for Linux and FreeBSD virtual machines on Hyper-V](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531031.aspx)</sub>

If the distribution is not supported, it is not advised to use them in production. Even if there are ways to implement support on a non-listed distribution.

Comment: It's all open source (including code from Microsoft), so I have the right to know. Whether it's supported it is ittelevant as I'm not seeking support and just educating myself. I run a non-production Linux anyway.

Comment: I didn't say that you would not have a right to know.